# Reinitalize a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the issue, i am running a complete ajax webapp with jquery plugins but i am having trouble reinitializing once i close the dialog.

```
function edit()
{
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        'Save' : function(){
                // Some function here.
        },
        'Close' : function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
        }
    }
});
}
```

The dialog is invoked by a button and all it does is call the above function edit()

I have tried these methods:

Scenario 1:

I click the button do the edit and in between i decide to close the popup using the close button (not the x button on top), the dialog closes.When i click the button again the dialog opens but now when i try to close i have to click twice because two instances of dialog are running apparently.

Scenario 2:

When i figured out that to avoid two instances i have to use

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close').remove();
```

instead of

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

This solved the multiple instance issue but now i can't open the dialog unless i refresh the page, any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls edit()?

Comment: it's just a link <a href="#" onclick="edit()">click</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this you remove the element with the id dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close').remove();
```

You should make sure in your edit function that #dialog exists before you call .dialog() on it. For example:

```
if( ! $('#dialog').length ) {
     $('body').append('<div id="dialog"></div>');
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is the method i have in mind to solve this now but the dialog has form elements so i have to write the whole html code for form in this. I was trying to find a better alternative way though.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the initialization of the dialog from the edit() function. Initialize your dialog separately, then make calls to open or close for the click handlers for each button respectively. Each time you call .dialog you're instantiating another dialog - just instantiate it once and auto hide it (which you're currently doing with autoOpen set to false) then pass open or close to dialog when you want to open or close it. See this [documentation](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

Create the dialog outside of the edit() function.  Once you call dialog(), that element is turned into a dialog.

In the edit() function, you just have to use the `$('#dialog').dialog('open');`

edit: add data passing

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        'Save' : function(){
            $('#dialog').data('param1');
            $('#dialog').data('param2');
        },
        'Close' : function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

function edit(somevalue1, somevalue2){
   $('dialog').data('param1', somevalue1);
   $('dialog').data('param2', somevalue2);
   $('dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the second issue still seems to be there, if close it and then open it it still retains the property of jquery events that got executed in the last dialog initialization.

Comment: What "property of jquery events" are you referring to?

Comment: @joza: I'm assuming you need to pass some parameters to your 'Save' button event.  The modal dialog supports this, check out the updated response.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to play with `clone()`.
something like this can help:

```
var dialog = $("#dialog").clone()
dialog.dialog({...})
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u should initialize that dialog with these code:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({    
        modal: true,    
        resizable: false,    
        autoOpen: false,    
        buttons: {        
           'Save' : function(){ // Some function here. },
           'Close' : function(){ $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        }    
}});
```

and then do ur edit code:

```
function edit(){
     $("#dialog").dialog('open');
}
```

hope it is useful to u~~~bless

Comment: Like i said in my question, the dialog('close') will work but if i open it again without refreshing the page i get two instances of dialog running.

Comment: r u open it with $("#dialog").dialog('open') or other way?

Comment: initialize the dialog only once, open it with .dialog('open') and close it with .dialog('close') is the right way to use dialog,I've never seen the issue like urs....